# How can I programmatically determine if a URL is a Universal Link or just a regular web URL?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

On iOS, how can I programmatically determine if a URL is a Universal Link or just a regular web URL?

Let's say you are about to launch the URL http://www.yelp.com from your own iOS app.  (http://www.yelp.com is a fully registered universal link.)

Case one) the user doesn't have the app installed -> You want to show them the website in an **IN-APP** webview.

Case two) the user does have the app installed -> You want to **launch out of your app** and deep link directly to the the yelp app by using  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]; instead of presenting a webview in app.

**Here is the problem:** 
*All you get to work with is the string url: "http://www.yelp.com"*   Your goal is to launch out to the yelp app if installed but present an in-app webview if yelp is not installed.

**Note 1: This question is only about universal links. Please do not give answers which use URL Schemes.**

**Note 2: This question is not about specifically launching the yelp app. The solution should work for any url to determine if it is a universal link of an installed app.**

Can you do this?

Comment: Use canOpenURL method to check if URL’s scheme can be handled by the system, if it can't  (yelp app not installed), then display webview screen.

Comment: In what case will canOpenURL return false for the given url `http://www.yelp.com` ?  (There is no scheme being discussed in this question, btw)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Detect if a link is universal using `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly`

Following is the solution:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url
                                       options:@{UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly: @YES}
                             completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                                 if(!success) {
                                     // present in app web view, the app is not installed 
                                 }
                             }];
```

Comment: This won't work if called by the app which is also the destination for the universal link.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue with my Swift 4 class below. It also uses embedded Safari Browser if possible. You can follow a similar method in your case too.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class OpenLink {
    static func inAnyNativeWay(url: URL, dontPreferEmbeddedBrowser: Bool = false) { // OPEN AS UNIVERSAL LINK IF EXISTS else : EMBEDDED or EXTERNAL
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // Try to open with owner universal link app
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey.universalLinksOnly : true]) { (success) in
                if !success {
                    if dontPreferEmbeddedBrowser {
                        withRegularWay(url: url)
                    } else {
                        inAnyNativeBrowser(url: url)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if dontPreferEmbeddedBrowser {
                withRegularWay(url: url)
            } else {
                inAnyNativeBrowser(url: url)
            }
        }
    }
    private static func isItOkayToOpenUrlInSafariController(url: URL) -> Bool {
        return url.host != nil && (url.scheme == "http" || url.scheme == "https") //url.host!.contains("twitter.com") == false
    }
    static func inAnyNativeBrowser(url: URL) { // EMBEDDED or EXTERNAL BROWSER
        if isItOkayToOpenUrlInSafariController(url: url) {
            inEmbeddedSafariController(url: url)
        } else {
            withRegularWay(url: url)
        }
    }
    static func inEmbeddedSafariController(url: URL) { // EMBEDDED BROWSER ONLY
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            vc.dismissButtonStyle = SFSafariViewController.DismissButtonStyle.close
        }
        mainViewControllerReference.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    static func withRegularWay(url: URL) { // EXTERNAL BROWSER ONLY
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey(rawValue: "no"):"options"]) { (good) in
                if !good {
                    Logger.log(text: "There is no application on your device to open this link.")
                }
            }
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```